# Where magento check if product is disabled

Tags: php, magento

When I insert the url of a product that is disabled magento redirects to the 404 page. I need to override that controller or whatever redirects to that page.

I have found this function in mage_catalog_model_product_status:

```
public function getProductStatus($productIds, $storeId = null)
{
    return $this->getResource()->getProductStatus($productIds, $storeId);
}
```

And if the product, which id is 9, is enabled returns {"9":"1"}, if disabled {"9":"2"}.
I changed the function to:

```
public function getProductStatus($productIds, $storeId = null)
{
    return array('9'=>'1');
}
```

but magento still redirects me to the 404 page.

Does anybody know where this happen?
Where magento check if a product is disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rewrite this method: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::getVisibleStatusIds()` and make it look like this:

```
public function getVisibleStatusIds()
{
    return array(self::STATUS_ENABLED, self::STATUS_DISABLED);
}
```

Then your disabled products will be listed in the frontend also.